P5.js svg export
I'm trying to implement an SVG export button onto my p5.js sketch. The button is visible, clickable  and saves a file but the created file then says:
"This page contains the following errors:
error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty
Bellow is a rendering of the page up to the first error."
Since I managed to implement it on a different sketch I don't know why it doesn't work on the other :(
The only difference I see is that the createCanvas(600, 1600); has an SVG in it. but if I put it in the code, the sketch disappears.
I've linked some libraries in my index.html to make the marching sketch and the svg export work:
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/p5.js-svg@1.5.1"></script>
<script src="scripts/p5.marching.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/p5.marching.min.js"></script>

Here the "marching squares" one that doesn't work:
let field = [];
let rez = 4;
let cols, rows;

let img;
let isImageLoaded = false;
let isExported = false;
 // Button zum Exportieren des SVG

function preload() {
  img = loadImage('assets/Screenshot 2024-04-30 at 11.38.35.png'); // Bild laden
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 1600);
  
  img.loadPixels();
  isImageLoaded = true;

  noStroke(); // Ändern Sie die Strichstärke nach Bedarf

  // Anpassen der Breite des Bildes an die Breite des Canvas
  let imgAspectRatio = img.height / img.width;
  let canvasWidth = width;
  let canvasHeight = width * imgAspectRatio;
  img.resize(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
  
  // Bild anzeigen
  image(img, 0, 0);
  
  cols = width / rez;
  rows = height / rez;
  for (let i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
    let k = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
      k.push(0);
    }
    field.push(k);
  }

  // Button zum Exportieren des SVG hinzufügen
  let exportButton = createButton('Export SVG');
  exportButton.position(10, 10);
  exportButton.mousePressed(exportSVG);
}

function drawLine(v1, v2) {
  line(v1.x, v1.y, v2.x, v2.y);
}

function draw() {
  background(255);
  
  // Das Video zeichnen
  image(img, 0, 0, width/2.5, height/4);
  
  let threshold = 255;
  loadPixels();
  for (let i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
      let x = i * rez;
      let y = j * rez;
      let c = color(
        pixels[(x+y*width) * 4 ],
        pixels[(x+y*width) * 4 + 1],
        pixels[(x+y*width) * 4 + 2]
      );
      let b = brightness(c);
      field[i][j] = b;
      fill(255); // b> grauwerte ändern um nur STROKE zu sehen
      noStroke();
      rect(x, y, rez, rez);
      let radius = map(c, 0, 255, 0, 80);
      noStroke();
      fill(0);
      ellipse(x, y, rez/0.5, rez/0.5);
    }
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < cols-1; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < rows-1; j++) {
      let x = i * rez;
      let y = j * rez;
      let a = createVector(x + rez * 0.5, y);
      let b = createVector(x + rez, y + rez * 0.5);
      let c = createVector(x + rez * 0.5, y + rez);
      let d = createVector(x, y + rez * 0.5);

      //HIER NETZ SENSIBILITät

      let threshold = 70;// map(mouseX, 0, width, 0, 255); 
      let c1 = field[i][j] < threshold ? 0 : 1;
      let c2 = field[i+1][j] < threshold ? 0 : 1;
      let c3 = field[i+1][j+1]  < threshold ? 0 : 1;
      let c4 = field[i][j+1] < threshold ? 0 : 1;


      let state = getState(c1, c2, c3, c4);
      fill(0);
      stroke(255);
      colorMode(RGB, 255, 255, 255);
      strokeWeight(3);
      stroke(map(b, 0, 10, 20, 360), 150, 255, 255); //state für random farbige
      switch (state) {
        case 1:  
          drawLine(c, d);
          break;
        case 2:  
          drawLine(b, c);
          break;
        case 3:  
          drawLine(b, d);
          break;
        case 4:  
          drawLine(a, b);
          break;
        case 5:  
          drawLine(a, d);
          drawLine(b, c);
          break;
        case 6:  
          drawLine(a, c);
          break;
        case 7:  
          drawLine(a, d);
          break;
        case 8:  
          drawLine(a, d);
          break;
        case 9:  
          drawLine(a, c);
          break;
        case 10: 
          drawLine(a, b);
          drawLine(c, d);
          break;
        case 11: 
          drawLine(a, b);
          break;
        case 12: 
          drawLine(b, d);
          break;
        case 13: 
          drawLine(b, c);
          break;
        case 14: 
          drawLine(c, d);
          break;
      }
    }
  }
  
  // Exportiere SVG, wenn der Button geklickt wird
  if (isExported) {
    save("mySVG.svg");
    print("saved svg");
    noLoop();
    isExported = false;
  }
}

function getState(a, b, c, d) {
  return a * 8 + b * 4  + c * 2 + d * 1;
}


function exportSVG() {
  isExported = true;
}


And this is the one that does work:
let img;
let isImageLoaded = false;
let isExported = false;

function preload() {
  img = loadImage('assets/cd-rom.png'); // Bild laden
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(800, 1600, SVG);
  
  img.loadPixels();
  isImageLoaded = true;

  noStroke();

  // Anpassen der Breite des Bildes an die Breite des Canvas
  let imgAspectRatio = img.height / img.width;
  let canvasWidth = width;
  let canvasHeight = width * imgAspectRatio;
  img.resize(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
  
  // Bild anzeigen
  image(img, 0, 0);

  // Erstelle den Button für den Download des SVG
  let button = createButton('Download SVG');
  button.position(10, 10);
  button.mousePressed(exportSVG);
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  for (let x = 0; x < img.width - 1; x += 45) {
    for (let y = 0; y < img.height - 1; y += 90) {
      let index = (x + y * img.width) * 4;
      let r = img.pixels[index];
      let g = img.pixels[index + 1];
      let b = img.pixels[index + 2];
      let radius = map(b, 5, 255, 5, 80); // Map blue channel to radius
      fill(r, g, b);
      ellipse(x, y, radius, radius); // Draw a circle representing the pixel color
    
    }
  }

  // Überprüfe, ob das SVG exportiert werden soll
  if (isExported) {
    save("mySVG.svg");
    print("saved svg");
    noLoop();
    isExported = false;
  }
}

function exportSVG() {
  isExported = true;
}


